# Share anchor links

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, anchor, share

I want to make a button that shares links in this form:

```
http://example.com/#anchor
```

but when i click it, it shares only

```
http://example.com
```

How could I make it share what I want?

Comment: Where's the [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @SamB, I didn't know what that was 7 years ago :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very detailed and it's not easy to understand exactly what it is you're asking for..

Since the share functionaliy was deprecated I assume that you are talking about the [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
As you can see in that page you can put what ever url you want into the "URL to Like" field, then click the "Get Code" button and use that code in your page.

You can put the code in any page, so if your page is: "example.com/#anchor" you can still have the button like "http://example.com" or the other way around.

If however you want the user to like "example.com/#anchor" but when someone clicks on the liked link he will get to "example.com" then it's not possible.

Comment: I was trying the exact opposite ... sorry my english is bad .. how to explain .. I only have one html file so just one page but different sections like `example.com/#macro` and when someone enters that link a js script scrolls down to that section or opens a lightbox with a photo ... and when I try to share a link in this form it shares instead just `example.com` but I want it to share the entire `example.com/#photo`.

Comment: This is what i was talking: [example](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fiulianonofrei.com%2F%23macro%2Fpanorama_3&t=Onofrei+Iulian+Photography&src=sp) if you look in the actual link you see the escaped link that I was trying to share `iulianonofrei.com/#macro/panorama_3` but in the actual page it shows only `iulianonofrei.com`

Comment: I just tried putting a url with hash (anchor) in the Like button guide page, then I liked it and indeed it liked that anchored url and not the generic one.  Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: Oh, you are using the share, don't use that, it has been deprecated and it's no longer supported. Use the like button instead.

Comment: The codes fb give you need to be wrote in the html file directly? Because i'm trying to write them with jQuery and I can't get it working.

Comment: You can add it dynamically, just call [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) afterwards

Comment: I done it but it still doesn't work as I expected. I have this code: `<fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" colorscheme="dark" show_faces="true" width="450" layout="button_count" send="true" href="http://iulianonofrei.com/#black_white/pissed_off">` and when I parse it, it shows it has no likes (my domain has 157 likes) as if it likes the actual link with the hashtag but on facebook it posts: `*username* has liked iulianonofrei.com` and not `*username* has liked iulianonofrei.com/#black_white/pissed_off`

Comment: They are probably putting it in a query string and then it gets mixed up with the original quesrystring.  Try to url encode it, that is: `http://iulianonofrei.com/%23black_white/pissed_off` or even `http%3A%2F%2Fiulianonofrei.com%2F%23black_white%2Fpissed_off`

Comment: I tried escaping it and even putting it manually and it still shows 157 likes. Is this even possible? It gets very frustrating I can't get it working.

Comment: Ok, I think that your problem is the `og:url` meta tag. The facebook scrapper use that url to index things, and so you need to have the entire url (including the fragment part) in that meta tag.

Comment: No. the facebook scrapper does not deal with javascript, it gets the http response and uses that data. What you can do is check the user agent string of the request, if it's `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` then you know it's the facebook scrapper, and return the right meta tags.

Comment: any ideea how to do this or any link that would help me? because i don't have any ideea how to do this

Comment: what are you using on the server side?

Comment: Oh. Well, if your page is completely static then you can't do it. You'll need to have a different page per like, unless you don't mind the og data to be common with all likes.

Comment: what if i make a php file ... like `example.com/?c=macro&t=bird_nest`?

Comment: You'll need all pages to go through the php, people share what they see, if they copy the address and paste it in the facebook status update then that's what facebook will scrap. So, yeah, you can do that with php, but all pages need to be served like that. If you are going with that then check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple; your URL string you want to share should be like this: http://www.domain.com/hello.html%23myanchor

The %23 will be transformed by Facebook into a #.

Comment: This doesn't work, and it doesn't fix the Facebook App bug with anchor links

Answer (score 1):

I just thought about this (because I have the same problem).
My idea is to share a php link with a variable, let's call it 'a' for anchor, which is the anchor **without #** so that facebook won't remore it.
Thus you share the link:
    http://www.mywebpa.ge/?a=anchor1
Then you just have to recover the value of 'a' with php and add a little script which makes you go to the anchor.
I hope it will help you.
Regards