# Facebook Share Dialog Strips Anchor Tags

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've been doing some research and I have yet to find any information that is relevant to what I'm looking for. I've included some links to questions I've already found when they're relevant.

I made a page in WordPress (though the CMS isn't necissarily relevant), and one page has a series of comments. Before each comment, I created an anchor tag, so that if you go to the URL "http://website.com/#10", you'll be brought to the tenth comment. The URL and anchors work fine.

I am now trying to integrate Facebook Share functionality into the site. Specifically, I want to be able to share the URL "http://website.com/#10", with the #10 included, such that a user will be able to share a specific comment on social media and not just the entire comments page.

Following the Facebook Share Dialog example, located [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), I crafted a URL that looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
    app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    &display=popup
    &href=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2F%2310
    &redirect_uri=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

With all of the X's filled in with valid information. Note that the "href" parameter is "http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2F%2310", which is an encoded version of "http://website.com/#10". The "#" symbol is encoded as "%23".

This URL works relatively well for sharing. When I click on it, I'm brought to Facebook, which gives me the same dialog box they show on the [Share Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905244/sharing-page-anchors-on-social-networks) developers page. However, after clicking on "Post to Facebook", I find that the actual URL that gets shared is, in fact, "http://website.com/?fb_action_ids=XXXXX&fb_action_types=og.shares". No "#10" anywhere in the URL.

Here's some information on the research I've done, to show that this is a new question (and to remove any repeated answers).

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905244/sharing-page-anchors-on-social-networks) question asks something quite similar to what I'm asking, and the only answer mentions a way to use Javascript to change all "#" symbols to "%23". However, I have already encoded my URL to do this, so the answer isn't relevant.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570578/share-anchor-links) question asks what I believe is a similar question, and the accepted answer basically says that the Share button is deprecated and continues by answering about the Like button. However, while the Share functionality may have once been deprecated, there is a fully working version on developers.facebook.com which I have already linked to. I would like to use this version, but with the ability to share links that include anchor tags.

Does anyone have any advice for how to proceed?

Comment: A hint... a far hint, try to put the address link http://website.com/!#10 . I'm going to run some tests now, but I'm almost sure that this would help. Almost.

Comment: Unfortunatley, using both "!" and its encoded representation, "%21", in the place you recommended yields only a "Share" page with no content, and when you hit "Post to Facebook", it brings you to the redirect_uri but doesn't actually share anything on Facebook.

Comment: I have a local example running this url on a window, and it does work with #dia-13: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.terra.com.br%2F%23dia-13&display=popup&ref=plugin . Maybe the endpoint /dialog/share, doesn't work as you need, but the /sharer/sharer does.

Comment: Well, it looks like that works! So strange that the more "advanced" Share Dialog doesn't allow for #'s, but sharer.php (which half the internet seems to claim is deprecated, although apparently it was deprecated at one point and then brought back) works! Thank you! If you could add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as soon as I am able.

A question, though - do you knwo where I can find documentation for any of the options you tacked on to the URL? Like u=??? is the URL to share, but you also have &display and &ref. Where can I find a list of possible options?

Comment: Well, I was working on a comment here, but I'll put as an answer so I can use the code tag.

Comment: It appears from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters

That Facebook doesn't allow any custom parameters on with sharer.php, only the OG meta tags from within the page itself. It seems to allow some more customization in the Share Dialog, which can't handle anchor tags. How frustrating! Oh well, at least this has the functionality I was looking for, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dialog does not seems to allow the URL to have #10, as you need.

Instead you may use, for exemple:
`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.terra.com.br%2F%23dia-13&display=popup&ref=plugin`;

What can be done is to open a window by javascript, using this URL, where `u` refers to URL.

So far, there isn't a documentation that describes what parameters can be used with the URL. What is known is that images, title and description may be declared by `<meta>` tags using `og:image`, for example, to ensure some default content.

As stated here: http://okaypl.us/blog/facebook-share-dialog-longer-accepts-custom-parameters/

Some old parameters that **probably are not working anymore** are found in similar questions like:
[how to pass parameter like title,summary and image in facebook sharer url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652041/how-to-pass-parameter-like-title-summary-and-image-in-facebook-sharer-url).