# Use a different link from OG:URL when story is published

Tags: object, facebook-javascript-sdk, action, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

I'm using a custom action and I'm creating my facebook object on a different page than the page the user is meant to visit when they click the story on their timeline.

Is there any way I can sneak the right URL back in?

EG. To publish story from XYZ website, an object is automatically generated on ABC page for facebook to consume. We want the user to click on their timeline and still visit the XYZ page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is with a meta redirect in your objects meta tags.

`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://XYZwebsite">`

Comment: This wouldn't work because I don't need to redirect every time. Only when The link to the facebook object is clicked from a Facebook timeline.

Comment: Then you could just make sure that the published story has a ?redirect=true in it, and hide/show the meta-redirect. Also, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent for detecting the Facebook bot when creating your boject.