# Facebook can't read dynamic og tags on a page developed by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, prerender

I'm developing a MEAN stack application (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node), and i want to share some pages on a Facebook fun page and have a personalised link like this one.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s414/sh/6c61c036-abc6-4eb9-b355-41af05760979/45fce4c1795580266f1247dba3452d62/res/31e7a3bd-7258-4910-bb05-5e2e61cd2d96/skitch.png

I'm using dynamic og tags to show different data on shared link

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<!-- Open Graph --> 
<meta property="og:title" content="{{og_title}}" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="{{og_url}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{og_image}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{og_description}}" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MYSITENAME" /> 
<meta property="fb:admins" content="MYAPPID" />
```

These variable are retrieved from server by a $http.get()

I'm using also prerender.io server running on my EC2 instance (on port 3000), in order to allow my javascript pages to be crawled perfectly.

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://'+ config.DNS +':3000/'));
```

Prerender is working fine, because when i type

```
http://DOMAINE.com:3000/http://DOMAINE.com/items/5376899f3230687806000016
```

i get a snapshot of the page and when i show the code source of this page i get correct data.

```
<!-- Open Graph data --> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Pink floyd CD"> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="DOMAINE.com:80/items/53763aad67afe39d05000017">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fpid.s3.amazonaws.com/items/4748_DarkSideOfTheMoon.jpg">
....
```

My problem is when i share this url on Facebook

```
http://DOMAINE.com/items/5376899f3230687806000016
```

instead of getting a good link with image, title and description, i get this poor link

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s414/sh/ac398446-276e-46ae-bc1e-eab5fea5cc31/ac5339dc23b07ccaa853a0b9e86d4c4c/res/c99109cc-d038-4837-a303-dbb5f7ad376c/skitch.png

Comment: I'm getting Access Denied on that evernote link. I'm assuming Facebook just didn't get all the right info. Facebook only waits a few seconds so your pages need to prerender quickly. You can cache pages to fix this or speed up the loading of your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to create a page that is rendered from the server via node that has the appropriate information.   You can do this by checking for the facebook user agent and serving up a different page/route in node (instead of your angular app).  This page only needs to display the og tags.

[How to recognize Facebook User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent)

Comment: Hi Lucuma, Thank you for this good solution. I implemented it, but i get this error `Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received` when i test my link on  Open Graph Object Debugger. My request take ~10047ms to respond. So do you have any idea to speed up the response ?

Comment: You may want to create a new question about how to do whatever you are doing in Node.

Comment: never mind, i fix it, i will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @hic2h what was the fix?

Comment: Yes please provide the fix of this problem. I'm struggling with the same issue for a month now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some background info to this problem:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

How it works with dynamic rendering:
https://prerender.io/how-it-works

and here are some services you can use:
https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=angular.js+seo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=EBnSU-CNB6fc8ge-uIC4Aw