# Detect social bots in Node Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, seo, bots

I'm trying to detect for either of the following 2 options:

- A specific list of bots (FacebookExternalHit|LinkedInBot|TwitterBot|Baiduspider)
- Any bots that don't support the Crawable Ajax Specification

I've seen similar questions ([How to recognize Facebook User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent)) but nothing that explains how to do this in Node and Express.

I need to do this in a format like this:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res){ 
  if (is one of the bots) //serve snapshot
  if (is not one of the bots) res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is use the `request.headers` object to check if the incoming request contains any UA information specific to that bot. A simple example.

**Node**

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    if(req.headers['user-agent'] === 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') /* do something for the Facebook bot */


});

server.listen(8080);
```

**Express**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    if(req.headers['user-agent'] === 'facebookexternalhit/1.1') /* do something for the Facebook bot */


});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: OK thanks, but what are the Bot specific UAs for the list of social bots I posted?

Comment: I'm not sure, but they're going to be the same regardless of the platform of your server. The link you provided lists one for Facebook. I'd recommend investigating that elsewhere.

Comment: If you just google for the user agent of the bot you'll likely find results.

Answer (score 10):

You can check the header `User-Agent` in the request object and test its value for different bots,

As of now, Facebook says they have three types of User-Agent header values ( check [The Facebook Crawler](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) ), Also twitter has a User-Agent with versions ( check [Twitter URL Crawling & Caching](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#crawling) ), the below example should cover both bots.

**Node**

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    var userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
    if (userAgent.startsWith('facebookexternalhit/1.1') ||
       userAgent === 'Facebot' ||
       userAgent.startsWith('Twitterbot') {

        /* Do something for the bot */
    }
});

server.listen(8080);
```

**Express**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    var userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
    if (userAgent.startsWith('facebookexternalhit/1.1') ||
       userAgent === 'Facebot' ||
       userAgent.startsWith('Twitterbot') {

        /* Do something for the bot */
    }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2):

This node express middleware will analyze a bunch of different user agent strings and give you just a "bot==true" or "desktop==true" way to determine. I haven't used it and the readme sounds like it was just a trial project so I don't know how maintained it will be going forward, but it will detect all sorts of bots.

https://github.com/rguerreiro/express-device

Comment: npm package 'mobile-detect' also detects bots and is what I'm using in my projects.
const MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect'),
      md = new MobileDetect(req.headers['user-agent']);
    const isMobile = !!md.phone();
    let isBot = md.is("Bot");