# Facebook request got redirect

Tags: asp.net, facebook, redirect, geolocation

Currently my client have 2 websites, for example: abc.com and us.abc.com. They want that everytime an user from US access abc.com, he/she will be redirected to us.abc.com. That can be solved very easy, however after solved that issue, I have ran into another issue related to Facebook.

That's when an user browse abc.com and they click share facebook button somewhere in the website, what was shared is always what appear in the home page of us.abc.com.

What I think is that because Facebook server is in US, so when facebook made the request, it was redirected to us.abc.com => Cause the issue.

Are there anyway to white list facebook request and skip it from the redirect rule ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can detect that Facebook is making a request. You can do this by using the request headers, as explained in the question [How to recognize Facebook User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent)
.

Based on those user-agent strings, you can decide wether to redirect.