# Allow facebook to fetch page(og meta) which is auth protected

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am running Laravel 5.5 and i use the basic auth of Laravel.

I have a route called "**profile-completed**" and that route uses a middleware "**auth**" / a user must be logged in in order to see that page.

That route(uses a view) has a function which creates a "share dialog" - with the below function - of facebook. The problem is that facebook can't fetch the **og:meta** because the view(route) is protected and it redirects to `/login` as seen through [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=).

```
Redirect Path   
Input URL   arrow-right https://www.url.com/profile-completed
302 HTTP Redirect   arrow-right https://www.url.com/login
```

As we see above, it redirects to /login so it fetches the og:meta of /login page.

**Facebook share function** :

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          href: '{{ env('APP_URL') }}',
          picture: '{{ asset('"img/share.png') }}',
      }, function( response ) {
        // do nothing
});
```

**Question** : How could i let facebook fetch og meta even of a page(view/route) which is protected by a middleware?

Middleware it uses :

```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Comment: Change it so you don't force Facebook to login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as mentioned was the the crawler of facebook had no access to fetch a page which is protected by `auth`.

I fixed this by modifying

> Vendor/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php

Change the default `handle` function to :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{

    $crawlers = [
        'facebookexternalhit/1.1',
        'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
        'Facebot',
        'Twitterbot',
    ];

    $userAgent = $request->header('User-Agent');


    if (str_contains($userAgent, $crawlers)) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
        $this->authenticate($guards);
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

References :

1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748072/6140684

Comment: This poses a huge security risk. It's worth noticing that any user could fake the user agent (see user-agent spoofing) and it will let them through unauthenticated.